# Show/Hide Multiple Div with slow effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small problem, and honestly I am very new at JS.

With the help from good people here in the stackoverflow, I have manage to make this:

```
a href="JavaScript:;"onmouseover="showIt('logo1')"onmouseout="hideIt('logo1')"

img style="border:2px solid #fff;margin:-2px;" src="images/clients/1.jpg" 

onmouseover="this.src='images/clients/1a.jpg'" 

onmouseout="this.src='images/clients/1.jpg'"
```

followed by:

```
div id="logo1" style="display:none;"
```

JS: that i found on this site and its working perfectly is:

```
lastone = 'empty';

function showIt(lyr) {
    if (lastone != 'empty') lastone.style.display = 'none';
    lastone = document.getElementById(lyr);
    lastone.style.display = 'block';

}

function hideIt(lyr) {
    if (lastone != 'empty') lastone.style.display = 'block';
    lastone = document.getElementById(lyr);
    lastone.style.display = 'none';
}`
```

I have 25 of this logos. Now that all is great. But how to make the transition smoother. Not to be appear and disappear.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.fadeIn()`/`.fadeOut()` to achieve what you want,

```
function showIt(lyr) {
  $("#"+lyr).stop().fadeIn("slow");
}

function hideIt(lyr) {
  $("#"+lyr).stop().fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Comment: This works great but problem that comes out of it is my hidden object are in the same position so even if i increase the fadeOut speed still pilling up of div's appears for short period of times. Can I use function such as FadeTo between elements? Thank you so much for swift reply

Answer (score 0):

Toggling display is always going to show/hide your elements without a transition. There are numerous ways of achieving the effect you're looking for.

You've tagged this with "jQuery": try using [$.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [$.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

You can also use [CSS3 transitions](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/) by applying/removing a class on the element you want to show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement this with show and hide by giving time like this :

```
 lastone = 'empty';

    function showIt(lyr) {
        $('#'+lyr+'\'').show(500);
    }

    function hideIt(lyr) {
        $('#'+lyr+'\'').hide(500);
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbh2w/89/)

```
$("#toggle3, #toggle4").click(function() {
$(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
```

});

Comment: good, i learn some logic from your response. $("#toggle3, #toggle4") thank you